# How to compare a specific column in two csv files and output differences to a third file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, difference

I have two csv files named `test1.csv` and `test2.csv` and they both have a column named 'Name'. I would like to compare each row in this **`Name`** column between both files and output the ones that don't match to a third file. I have seen some examples using pandas, but none worked for my situation. Can anyone help me get a script going for this?

*Test2 will be updated to include all values from test1 plus new values not included in test1 (which are the ones i want saved to a third file)*

An example of what the columns look like is:

test1.csv:

```
Name     Number    Status
gfd454   456       Disposed
3v4fd    521       Disposed
th678iy  678       Disposed
```

test2.csv

```
Name     Number    Status
gfd454   456       Disposed
3v4fd    521       Disposed
th678iy  678       Disposed
vb556h   665       Disposed
```

Comment: are your two columns of equal length? or is there some identifier which can be used to match them? providing some sample data would be useful

Comment: @Dan they are not equal length unfortunately. the column gets updated so more are added in each new file. i would like for it to only include the new ones in the third file.

Comment: @pythonscrub Do you assume that test2.csv will add more names and you want to find them?

Comment: @Dan added an example of the columns with the extra value that i would like moved to a third file since it does not match the test1 file outputs.

Comment: @balderman yes, test2 will include all values from test1 plus new ones which are the ones i want saved to a third file.

Comment: @pythonscrub See my answer. I think this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below.

The idea is to read the names into s python [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) data structure and find the new names by doing set substruction.

1.csv:

```
Name Number
A 12
B 34 
C 45
```

2.csv

```
Name Number
A 12
B 34
C 45
D 77
Z 67
```

The code below will print {'D', 'Z'} which are the new names.

```
def read_file_to_set(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        return set(l.strip().split()[0] for x,l in enumerate(f.readlines()) if x > 0)



set_1 = read_file_to_set('1.csv')
set_2 = read_file_to_set('2.csv')
new_names = set_2 - set_1
print(new_names)
```

Comment: this returned all the values and not just the new ones. what may be the reason for this?

Comment: @pythonscrub I think you are wrong. See my extended answer.

Comment: there are more than just one column in the file so maybe this is why it returns a lot more information? Can i set it to only check the column 'Name' in both files?

Comment: @pythonscrub please share few 'real' lines from file #1 and few lines from file #2

Comment: @pythonscrub I have updated my answer to work with multi fields line. The code assumes that the name column is the first field.

Comment: for some reason it keeps returning all the information in the file and not how you said it should

Comment: @pythonscrub Double check what you are doing.. It should work.

Comment: all i did was copy your code over. Is there anything i would have to change in the code?

Comment: @pythonscrub share few lines from each csv file.

Comment: i did in the question above. The column name is 'Name' and then the names follow below. The names are randomized so they look like what i included above

Comment: Do you have more columns in your files? If you do? - please share it.

Comment: the columns are as follows: "Name" "Number" "Status" but i only want to reference the name column to compare values

Comment: what is the field separator ? why dont you just share few lines so I can test my code against it?

Comment: This explains why you get wrong results. The separator in my code is ',' while yours is  white spaces

Comment: @pythonscrub The code was modified to support your file format. It points to 'vb556h' a a new name.

Comment: i dont believe the file format is actually white spaces, it pasted in like that. I dont know exact what format it is but i guess you can consider them as cells in an excel spreadsheet. Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: If the separator is a whitespace - the code should work "as is". If it is not - you should find out what is it and add it to the `split()` function call.  Did you test the latest code against your files?

Comment: how would i go about determining this? Also, would it maybe be possible to make the values in the 'Name' columns in each file go to a dictionary and then compare the two dictionaries to return the non-matching values?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207295/discussion-between-pythonscrub-and-balderman).

Answer (score 1):

This should be straight forward - the solution assumes that the content of file2 is the same or longer, so items are only appended to file2.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\path\to\file1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\path\to\file2.csv")

# print(df1)
# print(df2)

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

df['X'] = df['A'] == df['B']
print(df[df.X==False])

df3 = df[df.X==False]['B']
print(df3)
df3.to_csv(r"C:\path\to\file3.csv")
```

If the items are in arbitrary order, you could use `df.isin()` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\path\to\file1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\path\to\file2.csv")

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

df['X'] = df['B'].isin(df['A'])
df3 = df[df.X==False]['B']
df3.to_csv(r"C:\path\to\file3.csv")
```

I have created the following 2 files:

```
A
1_in_A
2_in_A
3_in_A
4_in_A
```

and file2.csv:

```
B
2_in_A
1_in_A
3_in_A
4_in_B
5_in_B
```

for testing. The dataframe `df` looks as follows:

```
|    | A      | B      | X     |
|---:|:-------|:-------|:------|
|  0 | 1_in_A | 2_in_A | True  |
|  1 | 2_in_A | 1_in_A | True  |
|  2 | 3_in_A | 3_in_A | True  |
|  3 | 4_in_A | 4_in_B | False |
|  4 | nan    | 5_in_B | False |
```

and we select only the items that are flagged as `False`.

Comment: lets say the items are in arbitrary order. what would the code look like then?

Comment: I amended my answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that the data is lined up as in your example:

```
import pandas as pd

# "read" each file
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['gfd454', '3v4fd', 'th678iy']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['gfd454', '3v4fd', 'th678iy', 'fdvs']})

# make column names unique
df1 = df1.rename(columns={'Name': 'Name1'})
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'Name': 'Name2'})

# line them up next to each other
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

# get difference
diff = df[df['Name1'].isnull()]['Name2']  # or df[df['Name1'] != df['Name2']]['Name2']

# write
diff.to_csv('test3.csv')
```

Comment: the thing is that new ones will constantly be added to test2 so i cant make a hard coded data frame.

Comment: yes, replace the `pd.DataFrame` calls with `pd.read_csv`. I just created the dummy data so that the code runs.

Comment: this works fine if the added values are added at the end of the column. Is there any way to detect the added value even if its randomly in the column somewhere?

Comment: in that case you should probably use a `set()` method

Comment: can you provide me an example of this? Sorry for the hassle I am new to this and want to get a better understanding of it all

Comment: I think @balderman's answer gives you what you need. But basically you can do something like `set(df2['Name']).difference(set(df1['Name']))`, and then write the result out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207299/discussion-between-pythonscrub-and-dan).